# formatting decimal data type to show currency

Tags: sql, teradata

My table definition:

```
create table decimal_salary
(
salary decimal(10,2)
)
```

Now I am trying to use the below formatting for the salary.

I have a salary as 100000 in the table.

I try to gain the formatted output in the below manner, I get simply -100000.00

```
SELECT salary * (-1) (FORMAT '-Z(I)BN') from decimal_salary
```

Isn't the FORMAT supposed to append the currency?

Comment: Personally, I'd never rely on the system supplied currency symbol.  Usually, that's based on the current session, and the moment you deal in more than one currency, you're screwed.  You should at least be explicitly listing curriency used, if not defining some sort of 'money' type with that inside.  Otherwise, you're doing unitless conversion, and we all know where that can lead...  However, this will obviously require you to add the currency symbol yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FORMAT is only applied when there's a CAST from/to a string.

Only for BTEQ REPORTs it's done automatically, for anything else you need to add a CAST to a [VAR]CHAR, most datatypes also work with a simple TRIM:

```
SELECT TRIM(salary * (-1) (FORMAT '-Z(I)BN'))
```

Btw, why don't you simply use **-salary** instead of **salary * (-)**?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(SESSION AS FORMAT '$(8).9(2)') AS CHAR(15)) AS CurrencyFormatted;
```